# How to connect to VPN server from a machine I'm remotely controling thanks to another VPN server?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, openvpn, nomachine

So I have my router at home acting as a OpenVPN server. From anywhere I can connect to it to access my network. One of the elements in that network is a server where I host virtual machines for diferent purposes. One of the virtual machines is my "work computer" to which I can connect using NoMachine.

The problem comes when I'm using the "work computer" from outside and I want to connect that "work computer" to the "work VPN" which is a OpenVPN server running wherever. The moment the "work computer" tries to connect to the "work VPN", NoMachine stops working completely.

I don't know if the issue is with me having two OpenVPN connections, or with NoMachine, or what. I can still access other resources in my home network and having my router act as a Wireguard peer instead of a OpenVPN server results in the same issue. So I assume it's not a OpenVPN thing.

Is it because I'm trying to connect to a VPN server outside of the VPN the virtual machine is in while being connected to the virtual machine from outside the VPN the virtual machine is in?

Comment: 1) Does your personal VPN use a separate IP subnet from the LAN that the VMs are in? (Generally the case, though not always.) 2) Do you have _console_ access to the "work computer" through your virtualization host system (which should remain unaffected by this)? Can you use that to check its routing table while it is connected to the "work VPN"?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the routing of the VPN in the "work machine". All traffic was being re-routed through the VPN. Including NoMachine's traffic. Therefore not allowing me to connect because NoMachine could not send the packets to the device I was using to connect to the "work machine".

In Linux's Network Manager I had to tick "Use this connection only for resources in this network" and configure some routes.